# Why is jsPDF producing a blank document in my AngularJS application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, jspdf, html2canvas

I'm developing an AngularJS application in which we want to take an html document and download it as a PDF. I'm using jsPDF. The problem is that jsPDF is producing a blank document.

Here's a screen shot of the document I want to download:

[image]

Here's the code that downloads it:

```
function downloadHelpDocument() {
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    var html = document.querySelector('.cebm-help-modal-body');
    doc.addHTML(html, {
       callback: function (pdf) {
            pdf.save('help.pdf');
       }
    });
}
```

Here's what prints out when I type `html.innerHTML` in the console (the first part of it):

```
\n        <se-collapse title="Introduction" iscollapsed="false" identifier="intro" class="ng-isolate-scope"><div class="expander" ng-click="collapsed = !collapsed"><h4 class="ng-binding">Introduction<i class="far pull-right fa-angle-up" ng-class="{ 'fa-angle-up': !collapsed, 'fa-angle-down' : collapsed }"></i></h4></div><div class="se-expander-collapsed collapse in" collapse="collapsed" style="height: auto;"><div ng-transclude="">\n            <a id="introduction" class="cebm-help-anchor ng-scope"></a>\n            <p class="section-paragraph justify-paragraph margin-bottom-30 ng-binding ng-scope">\n                \n      The Baseline Editor is a tool for creating a baseline of energy data for a particular site.\n      It is generated based on a sample of data that the user deems to be an accurate representation of typical energy usage for a given period.\n      For example, you can select the previous year as your sample and the energy data for that year will be used to generate your baseline.\n      You can then compare that baseline against current or future energy usage as well as correlate it with other variables\n      such as weather data, water consumption, or other forms of energy usage.\n    \n            </p>\n        </div></div></se-collapse>\n        \n        <se-collapse ...
```

I'm referencing the CDN for both jsPDF and html2canvas (I'm told jsPDF requires html2canvas):

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
```

Note that I'm not on the latest version of jsPDF (2.5.1) but when I try the latest version it tells me: jsPDF is not defined.

I've tried several variants of the code above. For example, I've tried `doc.html(...)` and `doc.addHTML(...)`, I've tried passing it my html document and also plain text (i.e. `'<html><head></head><body>Hello world</body></html>'`). The only thing that did work was `doc.text('hello')` but I need to create the PDF from my html document.

Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem? Thanks!